# Erro em transformar equação paramétrica. Opengl e glut.h

Tags: c++, opengl

Minha questão é a seguinte:

> Sejam as equações paramétricas dadas a seguir, que definem uma
>   curva em função de t ∈ R:
>
> x(t) = sin(t) + 1/2*(meio)* sin(5t) + 1/4*(um quarto)* cos(2,3t)
>
> y(t) = cos(t) + 1/2*(meio)* cos(5t) + 1/4*(um quarto)* sin(2,3t)
>
> Use GL_LINE_STRIP para desenhar a linha da curva na cor branca, e
>   GL_POINTS para desenhar o ultimo ponto calculado, na cor vermelha.
>   Faca com que o desenho seja realizado em tempo real, ou seja, a cada
>   instante, um novo ponto é calculado, e desta forma veremos a
>   construção da curva em execuçãao, como ilustra a figura abaixo.
>   Utilize a callback Timer usando 10 milissegundos como tempo de espera.
>   Dica: use orto variando de -2.0 à 2.0 em x e y.
>
> [image: imagem]

Meu código está praticamente pronto, só que com apenas dois problemas.

O primeiro é: Ele não está fazendo curva! Simplesmente está criando apenas retas. Não sei se converti a formula errado, se tá faltando algum parênteses ou algo assim.

O segundo é: O ponto vermelho novo é criado, mas o antigo continua lá. Tenho que ver ainda um meio de apagar ou sobrescrever o antigo, mas esse de longe não é o problema mais importante.

Segue meu código

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void display(void);
void init(void);
void reshape (int w, int h); 
void desenhaEixos();
void projecao(void);
void desenhaCurvaLinha(float centerX, float centerY);
void timer (int i);
void desenhaPonto(float centerX, float centerY);

float minX = -2; //Parâmetros do glOrtho
float maxX = 2;
float minY = -2;
float maxY = 2;
float minZ = -1;
float maxZ = 1;

int k = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //Escopo de criação de janela
    glutInit(&argc, argv);//Avisa que será criada uma janela
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500); //Diz o tamanho da janela
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10); //Diz onde a janela vai abrir na tela, em pixel
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH); //Prepara o sistema para a janela a ser criada, é extremamente importante

    glutCreateWindow("FreeGLUT Shapes");//Cria a janela

    //Escopo de registro de callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);   

    //glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutTimerFunc(1000/*valor em milesegundos*/, timer, 1);

    //Demais
    init();
    glutMainLoop();//Fica esperando a ação do usuário



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



void display(void){
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);//Limpando o buffer de cor

     desenhaCurvaLinha(1, 1);
     desenhaPonto(1, 1);

     glutSwapBuffers();
     }



void init(void){

     glClearColor(0,0,0,0);//Escolhe a cor do fundo da janela, nesse caso, preto
}



void desenhaEixos(){

     //glLineWidth(3); //Caso queira mudar a espessura da linha

     glBegin(GL_LINES); //Indica que vou desenhar linhas

          glColor3f(1,0,0); // Vermelho
          glVertex3f(minX, 0, 0); //Estamos escrevendo o eixo X na tela
          glVertex3f(maxX, 0, 0);// Fui do mínimo até o máximo, da esquerda da tela até a direita

          glColor3f(0,1,0); //Verde
          glVertex3f( 0, minY, 0);
          glVertex3f( 0, maxY, 0);

          glColor3f(0,0,1); //Azul
          glVertex3f( 0, 0, minZ);
          glVertex3f( 0, 0, maxZ);

     glEnd();   
}



void desenhaCurvaLinha(float centerX, float centerY){
     float x, y;
     int t;
     glColor3f(1,1,1);
     glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
          for(t=0;t<=k;t++){ 
               x = sin(t) + 0.5 * sin (5 * t) + 0.25 * cos (2.3*t);
               y = cos(t) + 0.5 * cos (5 * t) + 0.25 * sin (2.3*t);
               glVertex2f(x, y);      
          }  
     glEnd();
}

void desenhaPonto(float centerX, float centerY){
     float x, y;
     int t;
     glPointSize(5);
     glColor3f(1,0,0);
     glBegin(GL_POINTS);
          for(t=0;t<=k;t++){ 
               x = sin(t) + 0.5 * sin (5 * t) + 0.25 * cos (2.3*t);
               y = cos(t) + 0.5 * cos (5 * t) + 0.25 * sin (2.3*t);
               glVertex2f(x, y);      
          }  
     glEnd();
}



void reshape (int w, int h){
     glViewport(0,0,w,h); //linha protocolo
     projecao();
}



void projecao(void){

     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     glOrtho(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ); // Diz agora, que o X da minha janela começa no -10 e termina no 10, o y também.
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glLoadIdentity();

}



void timer (int i){


      k++;    
      glutPostRedisplay();
      glutTimerFunc(1000, timer, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente o problema esta na função "desenhaCurvaLinha", você precisa apenas de alterar o tipo da  variavel t para float e no loop "for" você precisa alterar o incremento de t++ para t += 0.05 ou outra precisão, de forma que seu codigo fique assim:

```
void desenhaCurvaLinha(float centerX, float centerY){
     float x, y;
     float t;
     glColor3f(1,1,1);
     glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
          for(t=0.00f;t<=k;t+=0.05){
               x = sin(t) + 0.5 * sin (5 * t) + 0.25 * cos (2.3*t);
               y = cos(t) + 0.5 * cos (5 * t) + 0.25 * sin (2.3*t);
               glVertex2f(x, y);
          }
     glEnd();
}
```

Este foi o resultado da execução do programa em meu computador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que ocorria é que com o incremento de 1 na variavel t fazia com que fosse ignorado diversos angulos, assim, quanto menor for o incremento da variavel t, mais arredondado sera esta curva, por exemplo, ao utilizar 0.1 no lugar de 0.05, é possivel ver os pontos onde cada loop 'for' para:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Havia  me esquevido de falar sobre os pontos vermelhos, não é necessario sobreescrever esse ponto, pois a cada ciclo de renderização a tela toda é apagada, o que precisa é basicamente é desenhar somente o ultimo ponto no ciclo de renderização, dessa forma:

```
void desenhaPonto(float centerX, float centerY){
     float x, y;
     float t;
     glPointSize(5);
     glColor3f(1,0,0);
     glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        x = sin(k) + 0.5 * sin (5 * k) + 0.25 * cos (2.3*k);
        y = cos(k) + 0.5 * cos (5 * k) + 0.25 * sin (2.3*k);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
     glEnd();
}
```

Basicamente, o desenho das curvas parava no angulo k, então basicamente o ponto vermelho sera renderizado somente no angulo k em cada ciclo, veja a imagem do programa funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]